# Awkward result while reading file containing spaces in pathname using getResource() in java

Tags: java, eclipse, file, getresource

I have a project named Downloader containing files like this:

```
Downloader  
-->src  
   -->Downloader
      -->DownLoader.java
      -->AudioLinks
```

I have tried to access AudioLinks from Downloader.java by the following function.

```
public void readFile()
{
    {
        File file=new File(this.getClass().getResource("AudioLinks").getFile());
        if(file.exists())
        {
            System.out.println(file+" Exists");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println(file+" Doesn't exist");
        }
    }
}
```

It returned the following:

```
E:\Project%20Eclipse\Workspace\Downloader\bin\Downloader\AudioLinks Doesn't exist
```

But if I edit the function like this(replace "%20" by a " "):

```
public void readFile()
{
    {
        File file=new File(this.getClass().getResource("AudioLinks").getFile().replaceAll("%20", " "));
        if(file.exists())
        {
            System.out.println(file+" Exists");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println(file+" Doesn't exist");
        }
    }
}
```

It returns:

```
E:\Project Eclipse\Workspace\Downloader\bin\Downloader\AudioLinks Exists
```

The problem is that if I export my program to runnable jar it gives "Doesn't exist" in both cases. Could anyone please explain these occurances?

Comment: Don't read it as a File. Read it as a URL through _just_ the `getResource()`. Get rid of the File wrapper (or an an `InputStream` through `getResourceAsStream`, depending on the type required)

Comment: Jars do not contain files so you can't use `File`.

Comment: @greg-499 of course jars contain files. Try to open a JAR file using an Archive Tool (maybe rename in .zip on windows) and look what you get

Comment: @peeskillet, thanks a lot for your helpful comment. I've successfully accessed my file. I have used this statement:    BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("AudioLinks")));

Comment: You can post it an answer :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

peeskillet wrote in his comment:
Don't read it as a File. Read it as a URL through just the getResource(). Get rid of the File wrapper (or an an InputStream through getResourceAsStream, depending on the type required)

So, I've edited the function like this and found no error:

```
public void readFile()
{
    {
        BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("AudioLinks")));
        String text;
        try {
            while((text=reader.readLine())!=null)
            {
                System.out.println(text);
            }
            reader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```